# Debian Jessie armhf repo

Tags: ros, debian, rasbperrypi, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

would like to ask... is there anywhere repo with ros-minimal packages for debian jessie with armhf architecture?
and if there is not, is there a chance that there will be given that debian jessie is now official distro? :)

I wanted to setup my own jenkins, but realized I don't have machine strong enough ( based on what's recommended on https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment , but maybe I can work with something less powerfull? )

P.S: please, don't answer with things like "use ubuntu" or "compile it on rpi", I know these alterantives and they are not point of the question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236192/debian-jessie-armhf-repo/) by [veverak](https://answers.ros.org/users/25419/veverak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-06**:
Considering there may not be a near term build of ROS for Debian armhf:

Could you elaborate on the difference(s) between Jessie and Xenial which affect your choice?
Have you considered cross compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure what you mean though, are you asking if binary packages are built for `Jessie` for `armhf`? If so then [not so far for Kinetic](http://answers.ros.org/question/239466/incomplete-packages-for-kinetic-armhf-jessie/) AFAIK.

> is there a chance that there will be given that debian jessie is now official distro? :)

I'm not sure if Jessie is officially supported. Starting from Kinetic, Jessie seems to put on some restriction on the specification (see [rep-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)) but support for it is "not required".

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0